# I noticed for light wallet,it is BIP32 and BIP39,how can I import the wallet into metamask

Tags: wallets

I use github light wallet, it is BIP 32 and BIP 39, how can I import the wallet into metamask or myetherwallet, I tried but not working, also, the default path is m/0'/0'/0' in light wallet